# Swapping values in columns depending on value type in one of the columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A','B'],[8,'s'],[5,'w'],['e',1],['n',3]])
print(df)

   0  1
0  A  B
1  8  s
2  5  w
3  e  1
4  n  3
```

If there is an integer in column 1, then I want to swap the value with the value from column 0, so in other words I want to produce this dataframe:

```
   0  1
0  A  B
1  8  s
2  5  w
3  1  e
4  3  n
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace numbers from second column with mask by [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` and [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html):

```
m = pd.to_numeric(df[1], errors='coerce').notna()
```

Another solution with convert to strings by [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) and [`Series.str.isnumeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isnumeric.html) - but working only for integers:

```
m = df[1].astype(str).str.isnumeric()
```

And then replace by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`DataFrame.values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) for numpy array for avoid columns alignment:

```
df.loc[m, [0, 1]] = df.loc[m, [1, 0]].values
print(df)
   0  1
0  A  B
1  8  s
2  5  w
3  1  e
4  3  n
```

Last if possible better is convert first row to columns names:

```
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df.iloc[1:].rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print(df)
   A  B
1  8  s
2  5  w
3  1  e
4  3  n
```

or possible removing `header=None` in `read_csv`.

Comment: Cool stuff. Avoid column aligning is the key.

Answer (score 2):

#### `sorted`

with a key that test for `int`

```
df.loc[:] = [
    sorted(t, key=lambda x: not isinstance(x, int))
    for t in zip(*map(df.get, df))
]

df

   0  1
0  A  B
1  8  s
2  5  w
3  1  e
4  3  n
```

---

You can be explicit with the columns if you'd like

```
df[[0, 1]] = [
    sorted(t, key=lambda x: not isinstance(x, int))
    for t in zip(df[0], df[1])
]
```